# Recurrence relation in matrices

Tags: linear-algebra, sequences-and-series, recurrences

I have the following recursive sequence:

$Z_k = Z_{k-1} - AA^TZ_{k-1}xx^T$ where $Z_k \in \mathbb R^{n \times d}, A \in \mathbb R^{n \times d}, d > n, rank(A) = n, x \in \mathbb R^{d \times 1}$

$A$ is a constant matrix, $x$ is a constant vector. Theoretically, this sequence of matrices $Z_k$ is entirely determined by $Z_0$ the initial element of the sequence.

If I give you $Z_0$ you are able to find $Z_k$ for any $k$.

Suppose I want to find $Z_{100}$. Is it possible to find an expression for $Z_k$ as a function of $Z_0$ so that I don't actually have to find $Z_1, Z_2, ..., Z_{99}$?

Comment: This is a linear recurrence relation, so in theory it is possible to work out the general formula for $Z_k$, provided that the matrices $A$ and $x$ are explicitly given. Not sure whether there is an optimization for this special kind of recurrence relation.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Let $B=AA^T$ and $X=xx^T$. Note that
$X^k=\|x\|^{2k-1}X$.

\begin{align*}
  Z_1& =  Z_{0} - BZ_{0}X \\
  %
  Z_2& =  Z_{1} - BZ_{1}X 
  %
= Z_{0} - BZ_{0}X -B\big[Z_{0} - BZ_{0}X\big]X
  %
= Z_{0} - 2BZ_{0}X + B^2Z_{0}X^2 \\
  %
  Z_3& =  Z_{2} - BZ_{2}X 
  %
= Z_{1} - BZ_{1}X -B\big[Z_{1} - BZ_{1}X\big]X
  %
= Z_{1} - 2BZ_{1}X + B^2Z_{1}X^2 \\
  %
& = Z_{0} - 3BZ_{0}X + 3B^2Z_{0}X^2-B^3Z_{0}X^3 .
\end{align*}

So that by induction,

\begin{align*}
  %
  Z_n& =\sum_{k=0}^n-1^k\binom nk B^kZ_0X^k
  %
= Z_0 + \sum_{k=1}^n-1^k\binom nk \|x\|^{2k-1}B^kZ_0X\\
  %
  & = Z_0-\frac1{\|x\|^2}Z_0X + \frac1{\|x\|^2}
  %
\bigg[\sum_{k=0}^n-1^k\binom nk \|x\|^{2k}B^k\bigg]Z_0X \\
  %
& =Z_0-\frac1{\|x\|^2}Z_0X + \frac1{\|x\|^2}
  %
[I-\|x\|^2B]^nZ_0X \\
  %
& =Z_0-\frac1{\|x\|^2}Z_0xx^T + \frac1{\|x\|^2}
  %
[I-\|x\|^2AA^T]^nZ_0xx^T
  %
\end{align*}